# How can I close form Event from other Form c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 forms. They each have different codes with the same namespace.
How do I add a code from form1 to the form2 so that changes to form1 when form2 closes?
Emphasis is on the close section of Form2.

For example : I have label1 in Form1 and I have Form2. When I click label1, form2 is open. I'd like to change label1.ForeColor when form 2 closes.

Comment: Please show us your current attempt, what isn't working and expected output.

Comment: This might help with future posts: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

On closing event of Form2, you add the block of code that you want to excute for the Form1

```
  private void Form2_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e){

     <Namespace>.Form1.label1.ForeColor = ...
}
```

Have you tried something like this and it doesn't work? Upload your code if so and give some more feedback if it's possible.

Comment: The namespace wouldn't be required since OP says they share a namespace. Also, controls are usually private (and likely should stay that way), so I would assume this code won't compile for OP. Typically you'd add a public property to `Form1`, so that you can indirectly change *something* from `Form2`. Assuming that `Form2` knows of `Form1`'s instance, obviously.

Comment: `Form2` doesn't know anything about `Form1`. `Form1`, on the other hand, knows about `Form2`, since *it created* its instance. So, when you create the instance of `Form2` in `Form1`, also subscribe to the `Form2.FormClosed` event. When the event is raised, you know `Form2` is closed and do whatever needes to be done in this occasion. Unless `Form1` shows a modal `Form2` (`Form2.ShowDialog();`). In this case, when `Form2` closes, the code in `Form1` resumes after `Form2.ShowDialog();`. In this scenario, you don't need to subscribe to the event.